# Delphi's Filter equal function for C#

Tags: c#, delphi, filter

I'm working on making an Delphi program for C# Windows Form Application.

I've got only one problem. I don't know how I need to handle this part of delphi code: (note, it's working with an ridder r8 com on C#, it's working like with Databases, but you don't do query's like normal.)

```
dRWK.tbOrderrgB.Filtered := False;
dRWK.tbOrderrgB.Filter := 'volgnummer=''0'' and kmb='''+dRWK.tbOrderrgA.FieldByName('kmb').AsString+'''';
dRWK.tbOrderrgB.Filtered := True;
```

This ensures that only the `OrderrgB` is accessible when it has `volgnummer` set to `0` and kmb = tbOrderrgA kmb.

You can see `tbOrderrgB` as an row off the database. In Delphi, I use Titan table to get to the data....

How would I handle this in C#?

Comment: i know nothing about delphi, but it seems like it can be done with linq in C#

Comment: If you using same controls functionality should be same. Sorry but I cant understand where is the problem. Next time name, show types of variables that we could understand code. Also are you making winform application and trying to move Delphi code to c#?

Comment: @Reniuz, i'm making an winform application. And i'm recreating the program that is written in delphi in C#

Comment: @maxlego, i've looked it up, and understanded it a little, can't you make an answer with it? so i can understand it better?

Comment: What is the types of dRWK and tbOrderrgB?

Comment: That filter looks like an SQL WHERE

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but i don't use sql, because i use an COM of an program

Comment: @Reniuz, the type of tbOrderrgB = IRidderTable

Comment: And what is IRidderTable ? Does it have same functionality like c# DataTable ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula, IRidderTable is an method from Ridder R8 (http://www.ridder.nl/oplossingen/ridder-r8/). I use it with the COM of Ridder R8. And this is what the appendix of R8 gives about IRiddertable: 

description

An R8 table contains methods and properties to retrieve data from a particular table to manipulate. You can then navigate through the data of the table to navigate or add, modify or delete.

Comment: so search documentation and see if IRidderTable have filter functionality

Answer (score 0):

i reckon it should be something like this

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = x => x.volgnummer == 0 && x.kmb == kmb;

// apply filter for IQueryable<T>
queryable.Where(filter);
```